# Embed dynamic swf-file - Html

Tags: html, flash, embed

I want to embed my swf-file via html. This is a part of my code. The problem is that the file shows up too small with the 100% size settings. 
I need it to be fit into the browser's size.
Where is my mistake?

```
<div align="center">
  <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
      codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%"
      align="center">

    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="portfolio.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#2D2D2D" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall">

    <embed src="portfolio.swf" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" 
       quality="high" scale="showall" bgcolor="#2D2D2D" 
       allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you have one `</object>` too much

Answer (score 1):

```
add to your <style> code
    html,body{margin:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of: `width="100%"`

use the `style` tag: `style="width:100%;"`